# Build a blog archive block with code

Tags: blocks

I want to build a "Blog Archive" block with a custom module. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

- create a new folder in /sites/default/modules
- create a custom_blocks.info file inside that folder
- add this content in the file:

```
name = Custom blocks
description = "A short description of your module"
package = My modules
files[] = custom_blocks.module
core = 7.x
```

- create another file: custom_blocks.module (note that you've specified this in the info file)
- add this PHP code:

```
<?php
  function custom_blocks_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['unique_id_for_your_block'] = array(
      'info' => t('block info'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );

    // You can add more blocks here.

    return $blocks;
  }

  function custom_blocks_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
      case 'unique_id_for_your_block':

        // Put your logic here and generate the HTML you want to display in your block.
        $block['subject'] = t('block title');
        $block['content'] = 'Put here the HTML generated above';
        break;

      // Add more case statements here if you defined more than one block.

    }

    return $block;
  }
```

- go to your module page, activate the module, go to the block configuration page and activate your new block
- read more here:

  1. [Writing a Drupal 7 module](http://drupal.org/node/361112)
  2. [Drupal 7 Block API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/7)

Comment: The files should be placed in /sites/default/modules/custom_blocks, rather than /sites/default/modules.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this solution is not "drupal way" way of doing this, but it does the job. Here is the code that needs to be put into a custom block where and input type needs to be PHP.

```
<?php

drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#archivetree").accordion({ active: "h3:last" });});', 'inline');

$result = db_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL -18000 SECOND), '%Y%m') AS created_year_month, COUNT(node.nid) AS num_records
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('blog')) ))
GROUP BY created_year_month
ORDER BY created_year_month ASC");


foreach ($result as $record) {

    $created_year_month = $record->created_year_month;
    $num_records = $record->num_records;
    $year =  substr($created_year_month, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($created_year_month, -2, 2);
    $month_name = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month) );

    $archive_tree[$year][$month] = array(
        'month'            => $month,
        'name'             => $month_name,
        'num_records'      => $num_records,
        'year'             => $year,
    );
}
$i_year = 0;
foreach ($archive_tree as $list_year) {
    if ($i_year == 0){
        $output = "<div id='archivetree'>\n";
        $i_year++;
    }

        $i_month = 0;
        foreach ($list_year as $list_month) {

            if ($i_month == 0){
                $output .= "<h3><a href='#'>";
                $output .= $list_month['year'];
                $output .= "</a></h3>\n";
                $output .= "<ul>\n";
                $i_month++;
            }

            $text = $list_month['name'];
            $text .= " (";
            $text .= $list_month['num_records'];
            $text .= ")";
            $path = "blog/archive/";
            $path .= $list_month['year'];
            $path .= "/";
            $path .= $list_month['month'];
            $link = l($text,$path);
            $output .= "<li>$link</li>\n";          
        }
        $output .= "</ul>\n";

}
        $output .= "</div>\n";
print $output;

?>
```

I am currently working on implementing this as a custom module, but am not quite there yet.